# Linux Cron job getting error "/tmp/crontab.XXXXsIOyNm":2: bad minute while creating new job

Tags: linux, terminal, cron

I am trying to create a cron job, and I am receiving error

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.XXXXsIOyNm":2: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

I am using this:

```
0 0 * * * /apollo/env/DatanetServiceClientSIAA/bin/datanet --method POST --field jobRuns --uri jobRun/-/2544859/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
```

The only thing I can think is, is that it is going across 2 lines? As, I noticed after POST the font changes to white..

Would it be possible to put this script into a .sh file, and cron the .sh file?

If so, how would I go about putting the script in an/the .sh?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `@daily` instead of `0 0 * * *`? You'll see if the error changes, and it's 3 characters shorter, so you'll notice font change in different position, if the error is due to "going across 2 lines".

Comment: I am trying to achieve hourly? I possibly misunderstood syntax for cron time scheduling. If it is due to going across two lines? Would I be able to put the script into an .sh file, or better option? If so, how would I have to format said file. Thanks.

Comment: @Spartacus38 Currently you're saying "on 0 minute, on 0 hour, every day", so yes, it's daily. Hourly would be  `0 * * * *` = "on 0 minute, every hour", and you can use `@hourly` instead.

Comment: Correct syntax? @hourly /apollo/env/DatanetServiceClientSIAA/bin/datanet --method POST --field jobRuns --uri jobRun/-/2544859/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`

Comment: frikozoid how would I go about putting this into an .sh file for bash?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to put this script into a .sh file, and cron the .sh file?

You can put it into shell script, just don't forget about type definition in the first line

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Max length of the commant is however 999 as it is decribed here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/546342/crontab-maximum-command-length

It also explains you might have a problem with % sign